# Better way to center than display: flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

It was brought to my attention that the way I am centering things in a site of mine isn't the best way as it's not really centered. I've played with this for a few hours and haven't found a better way myself.

I have my codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQEJyw) and was wondering if somebody could point me in the right direction.

```css
section#projects > div.row > div.wrapper > img {
  height: 356px;
  width: 390px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 90px;
  letter-spacing: -3px;
}
.social-links span {
  text-align: center;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-right: 4em;
  /*space between*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  background-color: #c5c5c5;
}
.social-links span i {
  font-size: 50px;
  align-self: center;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.social-links span i::before {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.social-links span:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.social-links span:hover i {
  color: #909090;
}
#contactMe {
  margin: 10vh auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.social-links {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 7.9vw;
}
section#contact > div.row > div.col-md-12 > h2 {
  margin-top: 10vh;
}
section#contact > div.row > div.col-md-12 > h1 {
  margin-top: 11vh;
}
.social-links > div {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*space between*/
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.social-links div h4 {
  color: coral;
  margin-left: -55px;
}
```

```html
<section id="contact">
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <div id="contactMe">
        <div class="social-links text-center">
          <div class="mail">
            <a class="nostyle" href="mailto:email@mail.com">
              <span><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <h4>Email</h4>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="phone">
            <span><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <h4 class="text-center">phone</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="skype">
            <a class="nostyle" href="skype:kyle.c.r.fahey?call">
              <span><i class="fa fa-skype fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <h4>skype</h4>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your solution is correct. Just remove `margin-left` from  `social-links`

Comment: I wouldn't use flex for this; I'd just use a combination of `text-align:center` and `margin:0 auto` and `display:inline-block;`.  Play around with your codepen; first put a border on every element so you can see what's really happening, and don't put left/right margins unless you use the same value on the left and the right.

Comment: What you missed here is when you move the span by `margin-right: 4em` from the right and you have to move the h2 by the same amount from the right `margin-right: 4em`  based on your current code formation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends what kind of layout you make. In this case, it is very simple to put elements in the middle. You can use: `margin: 0 auto;`:

```css
section#projects > div.row > div.wrapper > img {
  height: 356px;
  width: 390px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 90px;
  letter-spacing: -3px;
}
.social-links span {
  text-align: center;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*space between*/
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  background-color: #c5c5c5;
}
.social-links span i {
  font-size: 50px;
  align-self: center;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.social-links span i::before {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.social-links span:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.social-links span:hover i {
  color: #909090;
}
#contactMe {
  margin: 10vh auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.social-links {
  display: inline-block;
}
section#contact > div.row > div.col-md-12 > h2 {
  margin-top: 10vh;
}
section#contact > div.row > div.col-md-12 > h1 {
  margin-top: 11vh;
}
.social-links > div {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*space between*/
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}
.social-links div h4 {
  color: coral;
}
```

```html
<section id="contact">
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <div id="contactMe">
        <div class="social-links text-center">
          <div class="mail">
            <a class="nostyle" href="mailto:email@mail.com">
              <span><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <h4>Email</h4>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="phone">
            <span><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <h4 class="text-center">phone</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="skype">
            <a class="nostyle" href="skype:kyle.c.r.fahey?call">
              <span><i class="fa fa-skype fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <h4>skype</h4>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: And remember margin: 0 auto is fully supported, flexbox isn't. Plus we have the same hat! *hi5*

Comment: Yes, indeed! This is a very simple case to use flexbox, and is not still supported in IE. Anyway, many apps use flexbox for layout. It is really amazing. :) @ObedMarquezParlapiano

Answer (score 1):

Add following css. These are css3 [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) properties for making elements center align.

```
.social-links {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

***Note***: I've removed `margin` from some elements in your styles. This property was fully excess there.

```css
section#projects > div.row > div.wrapper > img {
  height: 356px;
  width: 390px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 90px;
  letter-spacing: -3px;
}

.social-links span{
  text-align:center;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  background-color: #c5c5c5;
}
.social-links span i{
  font-size: 50px;
  align-self:center;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.social-links span i::before{
  display:inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.social-links span:hover{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.social-links span:hover i{
  color:#909090;
}

#contactMe {
  margin: 10vh auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.social-links {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

section#contact > div.row > div.col-md-12 > h2 {
  margin-top: 10vh;
}

section#contact > div.row > div.col-md-12 > h1 {
  margin-top: 11vh;
}

.social-links > div {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 4em; /*space between*/
}

.social-links div h4 {
  color: coral;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="contact" class="container">
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1 class="text-center">Contact Me</h1>
      <h2 class="text-center">Let's get the ball rolling.</h2>
      <div id="contactMe">
        <div class="social-links text-center">
          <div class="mail">
            <a class="nostyle" href="mailto:email@mail.com">
              <span><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <h4>Email</h4>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="phone">
            <span><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <h4 class="text-center">phone</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="skype">
            <a class="nostyle" href="skype:kyle.c.r.fahey?call">
              <span><i class="fa fa-skype fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <h4>skype</h4>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```